# java.util.logging: How to configure logging levels when deployed as a JAR file

Tags: java, logging, jar, java.util.logging

I have put my logger.properties file inside src/java/resources directory. Using this file I configure different levels of logging (for both console and to file). Now when I make a jar file of my project, how can I configure or change the logging level because then I won't have access to the logger.properties file.

Basically I want to provide users the ability to set the logging level before the run the jar.

Comment: Do you have to keep the file in the jar ?

Comment: Not compulsory, but I would like to know how to do it when we keep it inside jar and outside as well

Answer (score 1):

In general you shouldn't keep the configuration file inside the jar.
Instead, place it somewhere (depends on your distribution, usually it can be something like `$YOUR_PROJECT_HOME_DIR/conf` folder). When running the application specify the following property:

```
java.util.logging.config.file=<PATH TO PROPERTY FILE GOES HERE>
```

Here is a [good tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html) on java.util.Logging that covers this point among others.

Answer (score 0):

You could use enviorment variables https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

You could also take the logging level you want to use as an argument for your program.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: @Mueller Currently, the logger.properties file has the level set to `INFO`. How can I change it after I package it to a JAR?